# Why does my vectorbt heatmap display the wrong values as a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, back-testing

I am trying to output a simple heatmap on a very small Pandas series. However the heatmap does not display all the values, nor are the values displayed correct based on the series data.

If I use a dataframe instead of a series, the values are correct but the labelling is not human friendly and I can't use 'y_level' or 'x_level' with a dataframe vbt heatmap.

Also this is the free version of vectorbt.

I create the series.

```
import pandas as pd
import vectorbt as vbt
index_values = [(0,0,0,0,0), 
                (-1.05, -1.1, -1.25, -1.2, -1.15)]
zipped = zip(*index_values)
index_names = ['rel_mom_entry', 
               'rel_mom_exit']

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zipped, names=index_names)
values = [6.26303, 4.462678, 4.079490, 3.214279, 1.861345]

new_series = pd.Series(values, index=mi)
print(new_series)

rel_mom_entry  rel_mom_exit
0              -1.05           6.263030
               -1.10           4.462678
               -1.25           4.079490
               -1.20           3.214279
               -1.15           1.861345
```

Now display the heatmap

```
fig = new_series.vbt.heatmap(x_level='rel_mom_entry', y_level='rel_mom_exit')
fig.show()
```

[Not all values are showing and values are wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnMgJ.png)

If I use 'is_x_category' and 'is_y_category', I at least get all values displaying, but they are still mostly wrong.

```
fig = series.vbt.heatmap(is_x_category=True, is_y_category=True)
fig.show()
```

[heatmap from series, mostly wrong values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s50tf.png)

But if I simply change this to a dataframe, the heatmap values are correct, although I can't make the axis labels human-friendly.

```
fig = pd.DataFrame(new_series).vbt.heatmap()
fig.show()
```

[Correct heatmap created from a dataframe instead of a series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfffn.png)

Can anyone help me understand why the behavior is different between the dataframe and the series, why the series data is wrong and what I can do to either fix the series heatmap or better label the dataframe heatmap?